# How to detect a mouse event when a user stop scrolling?

Tags: java, swing, scroll

I'm building an application in java that can scroll in an image. With Java Swing library, there is an interface named `MouseWheelListener` that provides a method named `mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e)`. My school assignment tells me that I need to detect when the scroll starts and when it ends to do a global action.

The event parameter doesn't give the state of the scroll (which is normal). With only that, it's possible to detect when the scroll start with a boolean, but it's impossible to reset the boolean because `mouseWheelMoved` doesn't tell when it's the last scroll.

```java
class MyPane extends JPanel implements MouseWheelListener {

    private int initialScroll;
    private int finalScroll;

    public MyPane() {
        initialScroll = 0;
        finalScroll = 0;
        addMouseWheelListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        // todo : some intermediary change
    }

    private void applyAllAction() {
        // todo : sum all action from initialScroll to finalScroll
    }
}
```

How can I call `applyAllAction()` when I stop scrolling in the panel?

**EDIT 1**: Rewriting the question because it was unclear.

Comment: You might want to re-read your question from the perspective of someone who knows nothing about what you're trying to do, because your explanation is very unclear. Are you using a MouseWheelListener or are you trying to implement something that you want to behave in a similar manner? What boolean are you talking about? And what event is that boolean meant to belong to? Your question uses a lot of vague terminology which makes it impossible to discern your meaning. "The conception of the code..." What code? Where's your code or a code sample demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Just as some background, there's no event thrown when the mousewheel stops. The mouseWheelMoved event assumes that the wheel scrolls a certain number of lines of text or pixels or whatever when the event is thrown. You seem to be assuming that there's some mouseWheelStopped event, but there is not.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I was deep in my head. I didn't think about being beginner friendly. I rewrited a part of the question. I hope it is more readable now.

Comment: A few hundred years ago, i.e. in my youth, there were clock on the wall which made an audible noise for each half-second and which needed to be rewound for staying (mostly) correct on time; because, believe it or not, they did not have batteries. If you forgot to rewind them you could easily tell, because you heard them suddenly stop ticking. Notice something? Obviously you did not hear them stop ticking. You only noticed, after a certain time, that you did not hear them tick. The computer has the same problem of not knowing when the user stopped scrolling with the wheel - and cannot tell you.

Comment: So the solution can only be to notice the non-occurrence of a wheel scroll event in a given time.

Comment: You may wish to do some research into the concept of a "coalescing callback" - essentially, each time you detect a mouse wheel event (that you're interested it), you notify this "call back monitor".  The "monitor" will, after a specified delay, trigger the call back.  So, each time you notify the "monitor", it will reset it's "clock" and begin waiting again - in Swing, you can accomplish this with a Swing `Timer`

Comment: Following previous comments, there is a similar Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643628/6746785) which may help. In the answer you can see how you can just use `Timer.restart()` each time the event is fired and use the `ActionListener` of the `Timer` to do your action after the user stops scrolling. You would need to fine-tune the time which the `Timer` waits before firing the event (ie when does the user stop scrolling). Note that instead of an `ActionListener` on a button, you would need the same code inside `mouseWheelMoved`.